# Passing a dialog from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-dialog

I am trying to create a simple loading screen, i dont need any progress bar or anything just an image.

What i need:-

-Start activity A

-Click button for Activity B

-Clicking button also starts a dialog that just displays my image while activity B is loading

-Once activity B is loaded i would like to keep the dialog displaying until my renderer has finished loading all textures.

Is it possible to pass an active dialog from one activity to another?

```
    //Activity A
    StartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class);               
            Dialog loader_dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
            loader_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
            loader_dialog.show();
            //this obviously doesnt work but is there something similar i can do?
            //intent.putExtra("LoadingScreen", loader_dialog); 
            startActivity(intent); 
            finish(); 
        } 
    });
```

if this is not possible is there some other way I can get the desired effect?

Comment: did your next activity has setContentView(R.layout.somelayout); ?

Comment: yes it does but i only want the activity B Contentview to be visible once the textures are loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the dialog box and let it appear in onCreate() or onStart() method of your next activity - B activity:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Dialog loader_dialog = new Dialog(context,android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        loader_dialog.setContentView(R.layout.loading_screen);
        loader_dialog.show();  

        ...
    }
```

}

I think that can perform the task you want.

Comment: the problem with that is that i then have a 5 second period from clicking the activity B button where i get a white screen then my image appears, if i have a new dialog in both activities then the one in A flashes up for a split second then white screen then the second dialog works fine

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the dialog to be shown during the transition to the second Activity, you can use one single Activity instead of two and change the layout of that Activity to use the layout of the second Activity instead of calling another Activity. However, this can be complicated since you will implement the features of your two Activities into a single one.

---

**EDIT:**

**You can use fragments instead of Activities.**